# Find a minimum threshold value for a constraint

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, constraint-programming

I want to find a minimum threshold value for a constraint, such that if this constraint is satisfied, the next one must be satisfied.

For example, given two inequations $f_1(X)\geq a$ and $f_2(X) \geq b$, where $X$ is a vector, and for each $x_i \in X$, $x_i = \{0,1\}$, I want to find a minimum $a$, such that, if $f_1(X)\geq a$ is satisfied, then $f_2(X) \geq b$ must be satisfed for all valied $X$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does valid $X$ mean?

Comment: $X$ is a k-size vector and only consisted of 0 and 1. I want to find a minimum $a$, such that, for any $X$, if $f_1(X) \geq a$, then $f_2(X)\geq b$, where $b$ is known.

Comment: You need to add some assumptions in order to make the problem solvable.  Apparently you have in mind a finite domain of size $2^k$, although you omitted that from the body of your Question.  So the second constraint you want to satisfy $f_2(X)\ge b$ defines a subset of that domain.  Now ask what the maximum value  of $f_1(X)$ is on the complement of that subset.  Then $f_1(X)$ *greater than* that value would imply $f_2(X) \ge b$.  However there need not be a *minimum* value for $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be a small tolerance. You want to enforce $$\forall X\in\{0,1\}^k\left(f_2(X)<b \implies f_1(X)<a\right)$$
So take
$$a=\epsilon+\max_{X\in\{0,1\}^k: f_2(X)<b} f_1(X)$$
If $f_1$ is integer-valued, you can take $\epsilon=1$.